# DIV's not lining up as intended

Tags: html, css

I have a total of three divs. Two background divs that sit on top of each other, and one for content which will be located within the lower div. My problem is I'm trying get the one with content to cover both the background divs, so I'm giving it a top margin of -20px. It gives me the correct result in Dreamweaver, but once I open it in Safari, the content div is pulling the lower background div up with it.

```
<div style="height:40px; width:500px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; background-  color:#CF3; margin-top:100px;"></div>
<div style="height:100px; width:400px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; background-color: #0FF;">
    <div style="height:80px; width:300px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; background-color: #F00; margin-top:-20px;"></div>
</div>
```

This is what I was trying for:
[Pic of what I want http://www.snapfoot.com/audio/good.jpg](http://www.snapfoot.com/audio/good.jpg)

What I dont want but am getting. I need the blue one to stay down, not go up with the red.
[Pic of what I don't want http://www.snapfoot.com/audio/bad.jpg](http://www.snapfoot.com/audio/bad.jpg)

Where am I going wrong? And thanks for any help!

Comment: The images you've used, are not showing up. I don't know if browsers even display tif files.

Comment: Web browsers cannot display tif files.

Comment: tiffs are just clipping for this example

Comment: example changed to jpg

Comment: You can position the the red box with `position: relative;` and `top: -20px;` and make it overlap the light green box.

Comment: now where has your fiddle gone... lol

Comment: I tried adding relative position with no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The HTML**

```
<div id="backgroundTop" class="center">
    <div id="content" class="center"></div>
</div>
<div id="backgroundBottom" class="center"></div>
```

By putting the `#content` div inside `#backgroundTop` you will be able to define a top margin for the content **relatively** to the background div. This is done using CSS (see below).

**The CSS**

```
#backgroundTop
{
    height:40px;
    width:500px;
    background-color:#CF3;
}

#backgroundBottom
{
    height:100px;
    width:400px;
    background-color: #0FF;
}

#content
{
    /*Here's the magic*/
    position: relative;
    top: 15pt;
    /******************/
    height:80px;
    width:300px;
    background-color: #F00;
}

.center
{
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**And the fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/yBq2V/1/

Comment: Why on earth would one use the pt unit in this case? Please explain. :x (no offense)

Comment: A point (pt) is the same size on every screen (1/72 inches). On the other hand, a pixel (px) size varies with screen density.
Plase see the following for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3557260/css-newbie-pt-or-px

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="height:40px; width:500px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; background-color:#CF3; margin-top:100px;"></div>
<div style="height:80px; width:300px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; background-color: #F00; margin-top:-20px; position: relative; z-index: 9999;"></div>
<div style="height:100px; width:400px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; background-color: #0FF; margin-top: -60px;">
</div>
```

Is this what you were looking to do?

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TzK6a/1/