# What Would Numbers Specified in UIButton Typography Mean?

Tags: ios7, uibutton, typography, hig

I see someone specified a typography of "Helvetica Neue, 65 Medium, 30pt" to be used for a UIButton.

I see other things like:

- "Helvetica Neue 45 Light"
- "Helvetica Neue 55 Roman"
- "Helvetica Neue 65 Medium"
- "Helvetica Neue 75 Bold"

What are the 45, 55, 65, 75?

This is for iOS 7; The HIG aka Human Interface Guidelines "Color and Typography" section was reviewed: https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/index.html

Comment: They correspond to the particular font weight of that font set. 45 corresponds to Light, whereas 75 corresponds to Bold.

Comment: So, I can ignore them. My choices in interface builder are like "Helvetica Neue Light 17.0"

Comment: In Interface Builder, it's a bit different: that number corresponds to the font size.

Comment: Make an answer out of it and I can accept it aka give you credit for the answer. :) Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They correspond to the particular font weight of that font set. 45 corresponds to Light, whereas 75 corresponds to Bold. You shouldn't worry yourself with them.

In response to your comment: In Interface Builder, the numbers are a bit different - they correspond to the font size.

Comment: BTW, what does "30pt" translate to in font size?

Comment: @finneycanhelp there are lots of resources around the Internet to convert font sizes, [like this](http://websemantics.co.uk/resources/font_size_conversion_chart/).

Comment: Thanks! I took a look. I am going to have to provide them feedback and ask them to specify things in font sizes instead of pts. I hope they understand how.

Comment: @finneycanhelp I'm reminded of [a question I asked a very long time ago regarding the differences between `pt` and `px` in CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3557260/should-i-use-pt-or-px) and got some very nice answers, it may be something you'd like to review as well.

Comment: Looks interesting. Thanks! I appreciate their attention to detail and communication effort. However, it'll be interesting translating these initial requirements to iOS. I don't think they meant this to be involved / complex. I think it's just the terminology they are used to or they got it from somewhere. Plus, we will need the discussion about Dynamic Type support being wanted as well and what that means for custom font size requirements.

Comment: I just googled for "how to specify font size in ios to a developer" to see if I could bridge the communication gap somehow. LOL!

Comment: A conversation revealed that the information came from someone well versed in photoshop, but we will need to translate those specifications to iOS specifications. Thanks for your help! :)