# In email templates, should font-size be in pt or px?

Tags: html, css, email, font-size

I am creating an email template, the specs that I am working to have the measurements in MS word font size. Being a print medium, this is in `pt`. However email is a screen based medium (https://stackoverflow.com/a/3557275/989852).

Should the font-sizes (and all other dimensions for that matter) in an email template be specified in `pt` or `px`?

Comment: If you have 3 valid reasons for using `pt` go for it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<sub>(*Excerpt*: Paul Dyke - http://www.adestra.com/what-need-know-using-fonts-in-email/)</sub>

> **em** doesn’t work with fonts in email as email clients have different default sizes.
>
> **%** is another scalable font unit, similar to em except 100% will always equal the default size.
>
> **pt** is sometimes used. One point is equal to 1/72 of an inch. But why use a unit that is a throwback to the printing industry?
>
> In my opinion, **pixels are the best option**. Email designs are often pixel perfect – lots of sliced images in different table cells that have to appear seamless. Having your text behave in a similar way makes sense.

And it's also my opinion

Answer (score 1):

I always use px for email template because most of the email i create is business marketing purpose. There is no need to print it, and i want font same sized for all devices. But now a days i'm creating some email template which is responsive at that time i'll prefer to em. since i need to re size according to screen. [why px](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3447/should-i-use-em-or-px-when-coding-for-html-email/)

Comment: don't use the link suggestion (vw, vh etc) in emails.

Comment: yes it is not supported by email clients since it is not so use full.