# Gmail on Android/Default Mail app on iOS shrinking text

Tags: android, html, ios, email, html-email

So I am working to build some new templates for my company to be used in email broadcasts, and am running into some trouble with mobile email clients. Specifically, my text gets way too small in Android and iOS.

Now, I can just use my media query to target iOS if necessary and adjust the font size as I see fit, but that's not possible as far as I know for Android, leaving me with incredibly tiny text.

My code is below, the main part I am having issue with is bodyleft cell, where the font size is a standard 16 pixels, and looks fine everywhere but mobile. -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; was not used as I DO want the size to adjust up, and it wasn't making a difference in this case anyway.

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

```
  <style type="text/css">
td img {
    display: block;
}
.ExternalClass * {
    line-height: 100%;
}
 @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
body[yahoo] .border {
    width:98% !important;
    min-width:auto !important;
}
body[yahoo] .main {
    width:100% !important;
}
body[yahoo] .body {
    width:90% !important;
}
body[yahoo] .spacer {
    display: none !important;
}
body[yahoo] .footer {
    width:90% !important;
}
body[yahoo] .bodyleft {
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
body[yahoo] .bodyright {
    float: left;
    width:100% !important;
}
body[yahoo] img {
    height: auto !important;
}
body[yahoo] .sideimagesa {
    float:left;
    width:48% !important;
    margin-bottom:10px !important;
}
body[yahoo] .sideimagesb {
    float:right;
    width:48% !important;
    margin-bottom:10px !important;
}
}
</style> 
</head>

<body yahoo="fix" style="margin:0px;" bgcolor="#EF9A9A">
<div>
<table style="border-collapse:collapse;" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#EF9A9A" style="padding-top:20px; padding-bottom:20px;"><table class="border" style="width:660px; min-width:660px; margin:auto; border-collapse:collapse;" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#F44336">
        <table class="main" style="width:650px; border-collapse:collapse;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
              <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
              <table class="main" style="width:650px; border-collapse:collapse;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tr>
            <td class="header" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;" align="center"><img style="display:block" src="http://images.theonlineimages.com/ima/650x200.jpg" alt="" width="100%" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="headline" style="padding-top:15px; padding-bottom:15px;" align="center" bgcolor="#F44336"><strong><a style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:24px; color:#ffffff; text-decoration:none;" href="http://en.wikipedia.org">This Can Be Your First Call to Action Link</a></strong></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style="padding-top:20px;">
<table class="body" style="width:625px; margin:auto; border-collapse:collapse;" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
              <tr>
                <td class="bodyleft" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#212121; line-height:22px;" valign="top">Any text you want to include to explain what you are offering would be placed here. This includes any and all incentives. The text can be <strong>bolded</strong> or <em>italicized</em> for emphasis. Individual segments of text can also have their sizes and colors changed in order to add emphasis that way.<br />
                  <br />
                  <strong><span style="color:#B71C1C">Header Text</span></strong> <br />
                  <br />
                  You can use headers to separate your ideas, and have <a style="color:#B71C1C" href="#">hyperlinks</a> throughout your text. Pictures on the right side can be used to show off what you are advertising. Greater or fewer images can be included, and they can be switched to the left side if preferred. Images will be entered at the exact widths shown, but heights can vary without issue.
                  <br />
                  <ul style="margin-top:19px;margin-bottom:19px;">
                    <li>A bullleted or numbered list</li>
                    <li>can be used</li>
                    <li>to itemize your text</li>
                    </ul>
                  All colors are completely up to you. This includes links, text, borders and backgrounds. Each of these can be changed to whatever color you like.<br />
                  <br />
                  <table style="border-collapse:collapse;" class="cta" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10">
                    <tr>
                      <td align="center" bgcolor="#F44336"><a style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:36px; color:#ffffff; text-decoration:none; line-height:42px;" href="http://en.wikipedia.org"><strong>Press Here if You Want to
                        Learn More</strong></a></td>
                      </tr>
                    </table></td>
                <td class="spacer" style="width:20px;">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="bodyright" style="width:210px;" valign="top"><table class="sideimagesa" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%; border-collapse:collapse;">
                  <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#F44336"><table style="width:100%; border-collapse:collapse;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                      <tr>
                        <td align="center" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"><span class="header" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"><img style="display:block" src="http://images.theonlineimages.com/ima/200x125.jpg" alt="" width="100%" /></span></td>
                        </tr>
                      </table></td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                  <table class="spacer" border="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%; border-collapse:collapse;">
                    <tr>
                      <td height="20">&nbsp;</td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  <table class="sideimagesb" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%; border-collapse:collapse;">
                    <tr>
                      <td bgcolor="#F44336"><table style="width:100%; border-collapse:collapse;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center" bgcolor="#BDBDBD" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"><span class="header" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"><img style="display:block" src="http://images.theonlineimages.com/ima/200x125.jpg" alt="" width="100%" /></span></td>
                          </tr>
                        </table></td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  <table class="spacer" border="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%; border-collapse:collapse;">
                    <tr>
                      <td height="20">&nbsp;</td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  <table class="sideimagesa" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%; border-collapse:collapse;">
                    <tr>
                      <td bgcolor="#F44336"><table style="width:100%; border-collapse:collapse;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center" bgcolor="#BDBDBD" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"><span class="header" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"><img style="display:block" src="http://images.theonlineimages.com/ima/200x125.jpg" alt="" width="100%" /></span></td>
                          </tr>
                        </table></td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  <table class="spacer" border="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%; border-collapse:collapse;">
                    <tr>
                      <td height="20">&nbsp;</td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  <table class="sideimagesb" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%; border-collapse:collapse;">
                    <tr>
                      <td bgcolor="#F44336"><table style="width:100%; border-collapse:collapse;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center" bgcolor="#BDBDBD" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"><span class="header" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"><img style="display:block" src="http://images.theonlineimages.com/ima/200x125.jpg" alt="" width="100%" /></span></td>
                          </tr>
                        </table></td>
                      </tr>
                    </table></td>
                </tr>
              </table></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style="padding-top:20px; padding-bottom:20px;"><table class="footer" style="width:625px; margin:auto; border-collapse:collapse;" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
              <tr>
                <td style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#212121" align="center">You can put disclaimers, contact info, or any other footer information you might want to include here</td>
                </tr>
              </table></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>

          </td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
</table></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

[Screenshot of the tiny text in Gmail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXOxr.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with Gmail that you are having has nothing to do with your font size or font declaration type. In fact, using EM or keywords as shown in previous answer can break your design/layout as they are inconsistent across clients (default size varies - see supporting answer here: [In email templates, should font-size be in pt or px?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27186166/in-email-templates-should-font-size-be-in-pt-or-px)).

The issue is that you have a declared width of 660px, which is much wider than the phone, so to make it fit the screen and not require a horizontal scroll, it 'zooms out' of the email, shrinking all of the elements in your email. Gmail ignores all that is listed in the stylesheet, meaning that all media queries become useless.

To prevent this, you should design in a mobile first environment using percentages and then using media queries, etc to style it to fit on desktop.

Good resource on this type of email: http://labs.actionrocket.co/the-hybrid-coding-approach-2

Good resource on acceptable CSS: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css

Codepen of example code: http://codepen.io/actionrocket/pen/EoCLH

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#ededed"> 
  <tr>
    <td>

    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style=" display:block; max-width:640px !important;" bgcolor="#ffffff">
      <tr>
        <td>

        <table id="holder" class="wrapper" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:100%; max-width:640px !important;" align="center">
        <tr><td align="center">
        <!--[if mso]>
             <table id="outlookholder" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center"><tr><td>
        <![endif]-->
        <!--[if (IE)]>
             <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="640" align="center"><tr><td>
         <![endif]-->  


        <!--2 column-->
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tr>
            <td>
            <table width="320" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left">
                <tr>
                  <td width="20"></td>
                  <td width="280" bgcolor="#ededed">
                  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                      <td width="100%" height="20"></td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                      <td align="center"><img style="display:block" border="0" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" width="100" height="100" alt=""/></td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                      <td width="100%" height="20"></td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                      <td width="2%"></td>  
                      <td style="font-family:arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:22px; line-height:26px; color:#454545; text-align:center;">Module title goes here</td>
                      <td width="2%"></td> 
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                      <td width="100%" height="20"></td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                    <td width="2%"></td> 
                      <td style="font-family:arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:20px; color:#454545; text-align:center;">Praesent laoreet sem orci. Maecenas male neq nec sem gravida commodo.</td>
                      <td width="2%"></td> 
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                      <td width="100%" height="20"></td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                      <td align="center">
                      <table width="160" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="w300" bgcolor="#a3a3a3">
                          <tr>
                            <td width="15"></td>
                            <td style="font-family:arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:16px; line-height:20px; color:#ffffff; text-align:center;">
                            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                              <tr>
                                <td width="100%" height="10"></td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>
                              <a style="color:#FFFFFF; text-decoration:none;" href="#" target="_blank">Call to Action</a>
                              <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                              <tr>
                                <td width="100%" height="10"></td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>
                            </td>
                            <td width="15"></td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                      <td width="100%" height="20"></td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                      <td width="100%" height="20" bgcolor="#ffffff"></td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                  </td>
                  <td width="20"></td>
                </tr>
             </table>
              <!--[if mso]></td><td><![endif]-->
             <table width="320" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" >
                <tr>
                  <td width="20"></td>
                  <td width="280" bgcolor="#ededed">
                  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                      <td width="100%" height="20"></td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                      <td align="center"><img style="display:block" border="0" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" width="100" height="100" alt=""/></td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                      <td width="100%" height="20"></td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                      <td width="2%"></td> 
                      <td style="font-family:arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:22px; line-height:26px; color:#454545; text-align:center;">Module title goes here</td>
                      <td width="2%"></td> 
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                      <td width="100%" height="20"></td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                      <td width="2%"></td> 
                      <td style="font-family:arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:20px; color:#454545; text-align:center;">Praesent laoreet sem orci. Maecenas male neq nec sem gravida commodo.</td>
                      <td width="2%"></td> 
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                      <td width="100%" height="20"></td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                      <td align="center">
                      <table width="160" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="w300" bgcolor="#a3a3a3">
                          <tr>
                            <td width="15"></td>
                            <td style="font-family:arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:16px; line-height:20px; color:#ffffff; text-align:center;">
                            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                              <tr>
                                <td width="100%" height="10"></td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>
                              <a style="color:#FFFFFF; text-decoration:none;" href="#" target="_blank">Call to Action</a>
                              <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                              <tr>
                                <td width="100%" height="10"></td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>
                            </td>
                            <td width="15"></td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                      <td width="100%" height="20"></td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                  </td>
                  <td width="20"></td>
                </tr>
             </table>

            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>    




              </td></tr></table>
        <!--[if mso]>
              </td></tr></table>
        <![endif]-->
        <!--[if IE]>
              </td></tr></table>
        <![endif]-->



</td></tr></table>
</td></tr></table>
```

Comment: You're correct. I overlooked that the width was 660px, Do you know which email clients do not support EM and keywords? I've never had issues with them up until now.

Comment: It is not that they are not supported, it is that there is no consistency. EM and percent (as well as keyword) are all based off the default font size declared by each email client, meaning it is not standard like on web.  I am not saying you cannot have success with EM, etc. but it is definitely highly recommended to use PX instead.

Comment: Great tip, the width declaration was indeed the issue. I tried making the template use only percentage widths instead and set a Max width so it wouldn't be too big on Desktop, and it worked. Looks ugly as heck on this layout, so I'll have to mess around with some other layout ideas, such as some one column ones.