# Be confused with 'pt'

Tags: css, mobile-website

I'm working on mobile webApp development these days, and I have read some article about it, but the description [here](http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions) confused me.

> Points are abstract units, they only make sense in this mathematical coordinate space.

So it means points are like `density-independent pixel`? Some place use `375pt * 627pt` to describe the iPhone6 and many articles about design use `pt` as a unit.

And the description of `pt` as a css unit from [CSS Trick](https://css-tricks.com/css-font-size/).

> A point is a unit of measurement used for real-life ink-on-paper typography. 72pts = one inch. One inch = one real-life inch like-on-a-ruler. Not an inch on a screen, which is totally arbitrary based on resolution.

And I remember there is a formula like `1px = 0.75pt`. So I can't tell which points are they talking about.

- Are these `point` the same one?
- iPhone6 has `375px * 627px` css pixels (when set `initial-scale` to 1.0), so why some place use `pt`?
- Does the number `12pt` in designers' article means `12px`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3557260/should-i-use-pt-or-px

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Designers makes designs with the theory of `1pt == 1px` (in photoshop is the same in most configurations), but in the real web world this isn't correct because 1 point is not 1 pixel.

- The `pt` unit in CSS is recommended to use only in printer versions of a page (because the relations with the inches).
- iPhone6 has got that resolution but if you change to points it may crash sometimes, in most devices.
- Maybe yes, but don't trust designers that thinks in web the `pt` is the same as `px`, that doesn't real.

Here you are an interesting article from **W3C**:

https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html

Comment: So could I understand like this: designers live in print world, so there is actually no `px` there, and they are used to using `pt`, but we develop for screen world, and we use `px` to implement the psd.

Comment: Of course. In fact, if you change the measures in Photoshop from `pt` to  `px`, the units remains the same!! For designers, `1px == 1pt` so is a developer task to transform it in real scenario.